# Display Flat Rate Shipping Cost for Single Product Page on WooCommerce / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display the flat rate shipping cost for a product on its single product page.

From searching on Stack Overflow, I did find some solutions, but none worked quite as expected.

Currently, the Geo Location is being used, so I want to base the displayed shipping cost off of that location. Each product may have more than one shipping option, but I only want to display the flat rate fee for the individual product. E.g.

In the US - Product X - Shipping Cost $Y 
In the UK - Product X - Shipping Cost £Z

Currently I have the following code:

```
function shipping_cost_display_1() {
    $rates = WC()->session->get("shipping_for_package_0")['rates'];
    if (! empty($rates) ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            $method_id = $rate->method_id;
            $instance_id = $rate->instance_id;
            $rate_id = $rate_key;
            $label = $rate->label;
            $cost = $rate->cost;
            $taxes_array = $rate->taxes;
            $update_cost = ceil($cost *= (1 + display_tax_rate_on_single_product() / 100));
            
            if ($label == 'Shipping cost') {
            //'Shipping cost' is the Flat Rate
            echo $label;
            echo number_format($update_cost, 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is displaying on the product page, but there are some issues. It will display the correct price on one page, but then if I go to another page the same price for the previous product will be displayed. If I add something to the cart then the price displayed on all product pages will change to that, so it seems to be related to the cart somehow.

Is there a way to get the direct flat rate for the individual product rather than have it related to the cart? Since Geo Location is already active, it should be possible to simply pull the flat rate for the product based on the current location.

I assume this current issue is happening somehow due to `WC()->session` , but any input would be appreciated.

Comment: On what woocommerce hook are you adding this code?

Comment: It is an in theme hook that runs when a product page loads.

As I mentioned, it is working on the page, but it's not getting the correct information as it is getting the shipping cost of the cart, not the individual product. Any idea how I can access the shipping cost of the product based on the location of the user (location is known due to geolocation enabled)?